# Can PrimeNG allow drop row on datatable?

Tags: angular

I have a question. Can primeng allow drag a row on datatable to any component in angular 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current version of PrimeNG, you can't.
There is already a *new feature request* asking this at their GitHub, you can follow the discussion at this link:
[Row reordering with DragDrop #504](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/504)

In the meanwhile, you can try a workaround with the ng-template feature.

 Something like this:

```
    <p-column field="columnField" header="columnHeader">
      <ng-template let-item="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <span pDraggable="eventos" (onDragStart)="dragStart($event)">{{item}}</span>
      </ng-template>
   </p-column>
```

Please note that, with this workaround, you must click exactly on the span inside the table cell in order to drag the row.
Hope it helps.